# Angular Build production return fatal javascript invalid size error

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to build project with command:

```
ng build main-app --configuration production
```

Then I get below error:

```
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169224860
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000309AFEE5A0
1: 00007FF71F0C815F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114079
2: 00007FF71EFE343F std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<+65023
3: 00007FF71FCC2EE2 V8_Fatal+162
4: 00007FF71F846D35 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
5: 00007FF71F6F02F3 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+62771
6: 00007FF71F706E50 v8::debug::Script::GetIsolate+15840
7: 00007FF71F57A9A1 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26913
8: 00007FF71FA19701 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
9: 0000021BBA9BCCE5
```

I try to clean cache and delete node_modules but it's not solved,Then try to change version of nodejs but problem not solved.

How can I solve this problem and deploy my project.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and deleting the source is troublesome for me, so what I did was to:

1. Close VSCode.
2. Rename project folder.
3. Open VSCode.
4. Open the renamed project folder.
5. Trust the source.
6. Run the command again.

These steps fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I deleted the **.cache** folder in the root of the project and again ran **ng serve**. It worked.
PS: you dont need to worry about deleting the folder since angular would rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

delete source of the project and update them then rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

After check many ways, for my problem I remove my source and pull again then build, all things work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the project, update it from the source and rebuild it